# How does Very Sleepy find symbol files?

Tags: c++, windows, profiling, symbols, verysleepy

Has anyone figured out how the Very Sleepy profiler finds PDB files? It seems like it doesn't use the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH env variable.. I've had success by putting PDBs in the same directory as the executable and DLLs, but I'm trying to profile a program that uses a TON of DLLs and it's getting really painful. Isn't there some way to have it point to a symbol server?

Comment: Quick note. I had the same issue but very sleepy could find the pdb's for the dlls in the local directory but not the exe's pdb. I hacked it to work by mimicking the build directory on our test machine so that the absolute path in the exe resolved to the pdb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The path to the *original* .pdb file is getting included in the DLL.  Just don't move them.

The source code for Very Sleepy is [readily available](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy).  It uses the DbgHelp API, symbolinfo.cpp source code file.  The call to SymInitialize() allows a tool to specify the the search path for symbols, 2nd argument.  It passes NULL, that's where the buck stops.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I figured that first point, but the problem is that I'm not profiling on the same machine that built the DLL.

Comment: Weird. According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681351(v=vs.85).aspx) passing NULL to SymInitialize() causes the library to look in the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH env var. I'm not sure why it doesn't seem to be doing that though.

Comment: Tip: If you use process explorer, you can view all the strings in the .dll or .exe. One of those strings will be the full path to the original PDB file; just search for '.pdb' and it should show up. Then you can create an equivalent folder on your PC to put the symbols in